# Manipular String em JAVA?

Tags: java, sql-server, string, sql-server-2005

Tenho uma consulta de `SQL` que o conteúdo me traz assim:

```
fulano@mail.com;ciclano@mail.com
```

Eu preciso somente do primeiro endereço, tenho que desconsiderar tudo que esta a partir do `;`?

Comment: Qual é o banco?

Comment: SQL Server, a aplicação sempre funcionou, quando era cadastrado somente um email no cadastro do cliente no banco, agora inventaram de por mais um e deu problema

Comment: Desculpa qual a versão?

Comment: Qual a versão do Banco, @RenanPontes?

Comment: SQL Server Standard 2005, mas vou tratar apos a consulta mesmo.

Comment: Observe a melhor opção faça teste talvez compense fazer do jeito que eu implementei, talvez não, mas, antes de tudo teste...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for diretamente na `SQL` utilize um junção de funções, [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187748.aspx) e [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(email, 1,CHARINDEX(';', email)-1) from emails;
```

onde `email` é o campo que guarda os endereços eletrônicos separados por virgula e `emails` o nome da tabela.

*Resposta retirada:* [<sub>SoEn</sub> - How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

---

Uma adequação para pegar os e-mail que não possuem items separados por `;`, ou seja, apenas um e-mail contido no campo sem `;`:

```
select CASE WHEN Charindex(';', email)>0 
   THEN Substring(email, 1,Charindex(';', email)-1) ELSE
   email END
from emails
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187748.aspx)
- [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186323.aspx)
- [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Acredito que esta resposta é mais adequada

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas maneiras:

com indexOf

```
String result = "fulano@mail.com;ciclano@mail.com";
int index = result.indexOf(";");
if (index > 0) {
    result = result.substring(0, index);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

com split

```
String result = "fulano@mail.com;ciclano@mail.com";
String[] emails = result.split(";");
result = emails[0];
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxilio.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função split do Java para fazer isso.

```
String email = "fulano@mail.com;ciclano@mail.com.br";
String[] emails = email.split(";"); 
System.out.println(emails[0]);
```

A função split divide uma String em várias Strings usando o delimitador dado e retorna as partes em um vetor de String. Como vc precisa apenas o primeiro, é só usar:

```
emails[0]
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/Eye9NK).

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxilio.